# Missing space character before "et" word on career profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, languages

When a user has two ongoing experiences, it appears that there is a missing space before the `"et "` word on the French version of his career profile.

---

[image]

---

The English version even has a comma before: `", and "`. So jealous!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (2934).

Comment: You should've left out a space!The missed opportunity…

Comment: @royhowie there's nospace for such jokes here

Comment: Did someone say [SPACE](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/113/8/6/space_core_wallpaper_by_deathonabun-d3eq8r6.jpg)?